# Angular 10: conditionally render fontAwesome icon

Tags: angular, font-awesome

I am using Angular 10 and I have the fontAwesome icon working fine like below

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faStatus"></fa-icon>
```

I want to render the icon conditionally from a function, something like

```
<fa-icon [icon]="getIcon()"></fa-icon>
```

My `getIcon` is defined as below and I have already tried the commented-out lines.

```
getIcon(): any {
 // return "faStatus";
 // return ["faStatus"];
 return ["fa", "status"];
}
```

I always get the

> Could not find icon with iconName=status and prefix=fa in the icon
> library

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think faStatus is a valid font-awesome label, maybe in your component, you 've already defined faStatus = 'valid font awesome label', that why you can use `<fa-icon [icon]="faStatus"></fa-icon>`

You need to return the variabe faStatus in your function, and it will return the valid font-awesome label.
If you return string or array faStatus, of course it will find exactly word-by-word faStatus label, and in this case it cant find and throw an error.

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fontawesome-sample-vj6gbf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes, I did have `faStatus = faQuestionCircle` and that's why it was working statically. Even though your answer did not directly solve my issue, from your example, I noticed that icons need to be added to the library, if you want them to be loaded dynamically - which I was not doing. If you can include that part in the answer, I can mark this as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Okie, so actually you need to refer to the variable faStatus, not the string "faStatus" or array ["faStatus"]. Have a look at my update demo

Comment: I have already solved my problem (based on your StackBlitz). If you can add a note to the answer explaining the need for `return this.faStatus;` (instead of string or array of string), I can mark this as answer.

Comment: Updated, pls check

Answer (score 0):

**Note** that *faStatus* (or `['fa', 'status']`) doesn't exist to be rendered even with no condition!

Second, Keep your code simple as you can employ solutions like this:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="condition ? ['fab', 'github'] : ['fas', 'medium']"></fa-icon>
```

Take a look at this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fontawesome-sample-c3gzpe?file=src/app/app.component.html) to see them in action.